# Cannot scroll to the bottom of a div using React.js refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css-selectors

Hi I am building an application where there is a list and on component mount I always want to go to the bottom of the list.

Here's my `render` method

```
<div className="message-placeholder" 
                 ref={this.myRef}>
                <List
                    dataSource={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={item => (
                    <List.Item key={item.id}>
                        <List.Item.Meta
                            avatar={<Avatar style={{ backgroundColor: '#08c' }} icon="user" />}
                            title={<a href="#">{item.name}</a>}
                            description={item.message}
                        />
                    </List.Item>
                    )}
                >
                    {this.state.loading && this.state.hasMore && <Spin className="demo-loading" />}
                </List>
```

in my constructor I have created a new ref. Like so

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.myRef = React.createRef();
```

and my css looks something like this.

```
.message-placeholder {
    height: 300px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

now on everytime component updates I try to go to the bottom of the list. Here's how I am doing that.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
        this.scrollToBottom();
    }

scrollToBottom = () => {
        this.myRef.scrollIntoView({block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth'});
    }
```

However, this doesn't work I get the following error `_this.myRef.scrollIntoView is not a function`

Can someone help me out through this problem please. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using a dedicated package like [react-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-scroll)

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for scroll particular section to `bottom`

```
document.querySelector(".message-placeholder").scrollTo(0,document.querySelector(".message-placeholder").scrollHeight);
```

And `scrollIntoView` does not has good browser compatibility  check this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility .

Answer (score -2):

```
<div className="message-placeholder" ref={(ref) => { this.myRef = ref; }}>
```

Comment: Could you provide a bit more detail around the code?